# Lightning Components version of VisualforceAccessMetrics?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components

The [VisualforceAccessMetrics](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_tools_metrics.htm) sObject is very helpful to quickly get some understanding as to how VF pages are being viewed.

Is there an equivalent for the AuraDefinition (Lightning Components) sObject? I haven't been able to find one from Workbench.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no metrics object for Aura components. May be Salesforce will add this object sometime in the future. Have you thought about creating an Idea request?